# Flask per-blueprint error pages

Tags: python, error-handling, flask

I have a flask application that looks somewhat like this:

```
app.py
blueprints/
    www.py
    shop.py
```

`app.py` imports blueprint objects from each of the files in the `blueprints` directory and registers them with the `Flask` object in `app.py` with an appropriate subdomain (also imported from the file). Each blueprint registers error handlers, however these are only invoked when a view manually calls `abort()`, not by general errors (i.e. calling a non existent URL on the subdomain managed by `shop.py` invokes the error handler on `app.py` instead.)

Is there any way to force flask to pass errors to the blueprint that is handling the subdomain in which that error is occurring?

Answer (score 5):

Flask's documentation [says that this is not possible](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Blueprint.errorhandler) for 404s and 500s.  If you need this functionality you *might* be able to use a wildcard route in your blueprint to handle 404s:

```
@a_blueprint.route("<path:invalid_path>")
def missing_resource(invalid_path):
    return "There isn't anything at " + invalid_path, 404
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get you're suggestion. That route will match all routes routed to `a_blueprint`. I have most of a solution now, which I'll likely answer my own question with tonight but thanks for trying.

Comment: @Drakekin - I just tested using [the code in this gist](https://gist.github.com/svieira/7261308) and Werkzeug actually does the right thing in all these cases.

Comment: I feel so stupid for not thinking of this! Thanks @SeanVieira. I decided to raise a `werkzeug.exceptions.NotFound` instead though so that I can handle 404 errors like other registered error handlers on the blueprint.

Comment: Great answer! One huge caveat: this catch-all route only matches invalid paths under the blueprint's URL prefix. Eg: if `url_prefix = "/myapp"` and the called route is `<base_url>/myapp/some_invalid_path`, this will work. But if the called route is `<base_url>/mapp/some_invalid_path`, the app's error handler will be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can use current_app and put it in the blueprints. Something like:

**shop.py**

```
from flask import current_app

@current_app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(e):
return redirect(url_for('shop.index'))
```

Comment: This will overwrite the error handler that is set on the `current_app` for 404 errors.  I think what @Drakekin is trying to do is have the blueprint for `status.drakekin.com` use the 404 error handler defined in the `status` bluprint and the blueprint for `api.drakekin.com` use a *different* error handler.

Comment: I think I need to customize the error in a specific blueprint, instead override all.